# Equals method not working Java

Tags: java

So I have my equals method here in the class below, and I doesn't seem to be returning true when the if statement is true! I can't seem to find out why...

```
public class Player {

    private int[] anyplayer = new int[5];

    // constructor for each player at the table

    public Player(int[] anyplayer) {

        this.anyplayer = anyplayer;
    }

    // checks if the player has a winning bet in the european roulette

    public boolean europeanequals(){
        boolean truth = false;  
        for (int i = 0; i < anyplayer.length; i++) {
            if (roulettedriver.eurowinningnumber == anyplayer[i]) {
                truth = true;}
            else {
                truth = false;
            }
        }
                return truth;
    }
```

Here is my driver where I call the method:

```
public class roulettedriver {

    // declaring the two roulettes
            final static int[] europeanroulettegame = {0,32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10,5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26};
            final static int[] americanroulettegame = {0,28,9,26,30,11,7,20,32,17,5,22,34,15,3,24,36,13,1,00,27,10,25,29,12,8,19,31,18,6,21,33,16,4,23,35,14,2};

   // declaring the two winning numbers
            public static int eurowinningnumber = europeanroulette.getRandom(europeanroulettegame);
            public static int uswinningnumber = americanroulette.getRandom(americanroulettegame);


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner keyin = new Scanner(System.in); 

            // initializing the six players (First player) 
        int[] player1 = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}; // the numbers are set to -1 because 0 is a winning number
         Player first_player = new vipplayer(player1); // First player is automatically a VIP
            try{

               for(int i=0;i<=5;i++) {

                   player1[i] = Integer.parseInt(keyin.nextLine());

                   }
               }

           catch(NumberFormatException e){  

               System.out.println("Player 2 : ");  
           }    

            // booleans are set to true if the bets match the randomly generated number

                        boolean winbet1 = first_player.europeanequals();
```

And basically my equals isn't comparing the right values I think... Can't seem to make this work? Any input? The value is supposed to be returned in the boolean `winbet1`

Comment: `return` instead of assigning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code continues even after finding a match, potentially resetting `truth` back to `false`, and returning that.

You need to change the method like so:

```
public boolean europeanequals(){
    for (int i = 0; i < anyplayer.length; i++) {
        if (roulettedriver.eurowinningnumber == anyplayer[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

or using a for-each loop:

```
public boolean europeanequals(){
    for (int number : anyplayer) {
        if (roulettedriver.eurowinningnumber == number) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot a `break`:

```
if (roulettedriver.eurowinningnumber == anyplayer[i]) {
    truth = true;
    break; // here
}
```

Without it, the loop will continue and probably set `truth` back to false

Comment: Or simply `return`, which will finish the method execution.

Comment: While `break` would work, it's *such* a bad habit to get into in a situation like this...

Comment: Yes, and as another question has revealed, "Prefer to exit early", as stated and explained here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/is-it-better-practice-to-return-if-false-or-execute-an-if-statement-if-true

Answer (score 0):

While other answered, I want to add few notes:

- arrays are *zero-based* in Java, this code:

  `for(int i=0;i<=5;i++) {
      player1[i] = Integer.parseInt(keyin.nextLine());
  }`

  will throw an exception, you should loop until 4 (or better, `plater1.length`)
- follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and rename your class to begin with upper case, also try to name your variables like `firstPlayer` instead of `first_player`
- indent your code for a better and safer world

Comment: It is done on purpose! So that the try-catch pushes to the next player! But thank you for pointing it out